# Rails 4 JOIN GROUP BY and SELECT

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

I am trying to JOIN 2 tables in Rails 4, to perform a count and also keep a column of the joined table.

Models: User has_many :orders

What I want: the number of orders AND the date of the last order.

```
has_many :orders, -> { select("users.*, count(orders.id) as orders_count").group('users.id') }
```

I would like to select the created_at column in the ORDERS table like so

```
select("users.*, orders.created_at, count(orders.id) as orders_count").group('users.id')
```

But in that case I get an error

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "orders.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I need the FIRST created_at so I tried the SQL Aggregate Function "FIRST" on the created_at column

```
select("users.*, first(orders.created_at) as most_recent, count(orders.id) as orders_count").group('users.id')
```

But I would get

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function first(character varying) does not exist
```

Any idea how can I achieve this JOIN, COUNT and SELECT on the joined table?

Comment: Can you post you models relationship and describe exactly what you want ? You want the number of orders for each user ?

Comment: Just edited the question

Comment: @stefano_cdn, which version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: So I think you need `, class_name: "Users"` after your scope block. But I may be mad...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Would the following work for you?

```
User.joins(:orders)
    .select("users.*, max(orders.created_at) as most_recent, count(orders.id) as orders_count")
    .group('users.id')
```

Taking the `max` of `order.created_at` should give you the date of the most recent order. I don't think you want to have your `select` as part of `has_many` orders, since you're looking for a list of users, not a list of orders. If you'd a method that returns this active record query, assuming you'll use it more than once, you can add the following to your `User` model.

```
def self.with_order_info
  self.joins(:orders)
      .select("users.*, max(orders.created_at) as most_recent, count(orders.id) as orders_count")
      .group('users.id')
end
```

And then, you can call that method anywhere using:

```
@users = User.with_order_info
```

As a further note (to be 100% clear), you should keep your association to orders as:

```
has_many :orders
```

Comment: You'd still have to do another query to get the info @stefano_cdn is looking for though.

Comment: @jcuenod to get what info? I'm not sure what you mean. As far as I can tell my answer captures all the information the OP is looking for. I also changed up my answer a bit (since the `select` shouldn't be a part of the `has_many :orders` association).

Comment: Thx @JoeKennedy, I was also planning to use the select in an has_many :through relationship in order to fetch columns of the relation table. Here your answer works well, what if you wanted to group and keep a column that is not a date but a string : you could not use MAX function, but isn't there an aggregate function that keeps the columns without operation (I tried FIRST and LAST, does not work, as I mentionned in my initial question)

Comment: If `max` doesn't work for strings then I'm not sure if there would be an aggregate function that would work. Possibly you'd need a nested query.